# How to set MSDN to be always in English

Tags: msdn

I know that this isn't exactly programming question, but it is tightly related -

How the hell do I set MSDN to display everything in English? I'm Czech, and every KB or documentation article it automatically translates it to Czech with their translator, which result just in gibberish, and switching it to English requires couple of searching and clicks.

Comment: Are you hitting links to MSDN through a search engine, like Google? It may well be the case that this is the perpetrator, in which case you can stop Google (for instance) guessing your locale and specify desired languages using `Search Settings`.

Comment: I don't get this problem, although I live in germany, once I changed the language (in the top left corner, took 2 clicks), it has always stayed in English. Maybe you have cookies disabled?

Comment: @Beachwalker, This is case for every browser. Opera/Chrome, usually. One thing - I've got english OS, english settings, but it still realizes i'm connecting from czech IP.

Comment: I've changed `Which language should Google products use?` to English like @GrantThomas said and Google has started to show msdn links for en-US culture. Until this `Currently showing search results in` setting have my local language (Ukranian) and it was not possible to uncheck it.

Comment: Cannot upvote this enough...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Very legitimate question, I think.

You need to modify the url like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933414/automatic-text-translation-at-msdn-pages-how-to-turn-off). In your case change cz-cz to en-us.

Or better, let it do a browser plugin like Redirector for firefox:

[image: Redirector plugin set to force English msdn pages]

Comment: I use [Redirector for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/pajiegeliagebegjdhebejdlknciafen) and have this: `http([s]?):\/\/(docs|msdn)\.microsoft\.com\/es-es\/(.*)` to `http$1://$2.microsoft.com/en-us/$3`

Answer (score 63):

I wrote a simple dedicated browser extension for this. Unlike the Redirector plugin, no configuration is required.

It's called "FFS MSDN in English" and is available for:

- [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ffs-msdn-in-english/ddaknggefjjgpnlhiejepbiplceedmfl?hl=en)
- [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ffs-msdn-in-english/)
- [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/ffs-msdn-in-english/?display=en)

It simply redirects any localised MSDN (or docs.microsoft) page to the english (en-us) version.

The rather trivial sources can be found at https://github.com/AirLancer/ffs_msdn_in_english

Comment: Still working perfectly fine. Would it be possible to update the extension and add azure.microsoft.com to the domains list?

Comment: Might be a good Christmas vacation project.
I'm thinking about moving the Icon to the URL bar when you visit the site instead of displaying it permanently.
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I like the icon in the URL bar idea. Closer to the actual domain.

Comment: reactivated my account just too make a +1 for this addon...
Hope somebody at microsoft reads this. Hopefully the same person who made seperators in CSV ; instead of , in german or made localized incompatible excel macros

Comment: Great extension, however I find it extremely ridiculous that we need it in the first place.

Comment: Too bad though you don't reply to issues on the github page (anymore).

Comment: @kipusoep my bad. I started with the PRs yesterday but my laptop had an update in the middle of it. I'll try again tonight.

Answer (score 28):

[image: MSDN Set Language]

You can select your default language from bottom left of the page.

**Edit**

New docs site has an easier option to view in English. However, the setting is not permanent.

[image: Microsoft Docs View in English]

Comment: But you need to do this every time, are there settings which always apply? maybe with an microsoft account?

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it by installing a redirector plugin for chrome:
http://bendavis78.github.io/chrome-extension-redirector/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google search, you need to change language preferences for Google itself (you don't need to be logged in)<sup>1</sup>:

1. Go to https://google.com
2. Click *Settings > Search settings* on the bottom right corner.
3. Proceed to *Languages* tab.
4. Choose *English* as preferred.

---

<sup>1</sup> You might also need to do what [pr0gg3r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59566344/10036950) and [Beachwalker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978308/10036950) advise.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to rewrite google's search engine links using this Tampermonkey userscript:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix learn.microsoft.com links on google.com
// @description  Changes all links to en-us versions.
// @include      /^http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?google\.[a-z]{2,3}\/.*$/
// @noframes
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    let re = /^(https?:\/\/(docs|msdn).microsoft.com)\/(\w+\-\w+)\/(.*)/i;
    const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (const link of links) {
        let m = re.exec(link.href);
        if (!m) continue;
        const clone = link.cloneNode(true);
        clone.removeAttribute('onmousedown');
        clone.href = `${m[1]}/en-us/${m[4]}`;
        link.replaceWith(clone);
    }
})();
```

Edit 2021-01-28: Remove onmousedown attribute event from link. Stops link capture and substitution of google's own redirect link.

Comment: Use "// @include      /^http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?google\.[a-z]{2,3}\/.*$/" instead of match. Yours match catch ".com" google only.

Comment: @Mabakay Thanks, i updated my response. I've also added @@noframes to stop activation in google iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to use extensions because I consider their required permissions to be a major security risk. Furthermore MSDN is not the only site where translations sucks. So for me the best solution was to change the language settings in Windows 10. Add English to your "Preferred languages" and set it to be 1st. Apps and websites will appear in the first language in the list that they support.

[image]

Comment: This does make en-US the default if you navigate to microsoft docs, but when you do a websearch for ms content you easily get stuck with a different language (typically your browser language). A common situation that AirLancer's "FFS MSDN in English" plugin handles perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have the choice between the translated and *en-us* version.
I authored the following UserScript... to be used in [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for instance.

It does what it pretends in the @description.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Link to MSDN in en-us
// @description  Adds a link in the top left corner of the translated MSDN pages allowing to jump to en-us version.
// @match        http*://learn.microsoft.com/*
// @match        http*://msdn.microsoft.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    let url = location.href;
    let rx = /^http([s]?):\/\/(docs|msdn)\.microsoft\.com\/(\w+\-\w+)\/(.*)$/i;
    let match;
    if ( match = rx.exec(url) ) {
        if (match[3] !== 'en-us') {
            var targetUrl = url.replace(rx, "http$1://$2.microsoft.com/en-us/$4");
            jQuery("body").prepend(
                jQuery('<a>en-us</a>').attr('href', targetUrl)
            );
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox > Settings > "Language and Appearance" section there is below some Language settings a button next to a label that says:

"Choose your preferred language for displaying pages"

There you can setup a ordered list of languages. I have added english and moved it to the top of the list.
Now after a restart the same, previously opened msdn links do not auto translate.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the browser you're using but most browsers send info about the client to the server (incl. preferred language). So one option might be to set the default language to english (as done here for [Firefox](http://whatismyipaddress.ricmedia.com/help/browser_language/firefox/)).

Comment: Seems that it looks at the ip only. I removed all the languages from my "languages" chrome setting, but msdn still was showing me russian version.