# Set/Change Default Organization in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I had an existing organization on Azure DevOps (say, `org1`) to host my main projects and I recently added another organization (say, `org2`) to host projects I work on for a non-profit where I volunteer.

After creating `org2`, whenever I log into Azure DevOps or access `https://dev.azure.com`, it redirects me to `https://dev.azure.com/org2` instead of `https://dev.azure.com/org1` as it did before I created the new organization.  Unfortunately, I access `org1` much more frequently so this is a silly inconvenience.

How can I set or change the default organization so that my default page is `https://dev.azure.com/org1` again?

Comment: Try to switch to the org1, sign out current account, then re-sign in to the Azure Devops. Check if it redirects to the org1?

Comment: I think I tried that originally but, just to be sure, I tried it a few times just now and it didn't have the desired effect.  Luckily, it now seems to prefer my original organization so I'm less bothered by it personally but I would still like to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not setting for that at this time.
You can work around this issue by installing browser extension that will all way's redirect you 
to
https://dev.azure.com/org1
if you type only
https://dev.azure.com

Like this was suggested here to have allways MSDN in eng
[How to set MSDN to be always in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274463/how-to-set-msdn-to-be-always-in-english)

Comment: It looks like this is the best answer we can get, currently.  Hopefully they add a setting for this at some point but this will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the the name of the organization on the end of the URL and it will take you straight to the desired organization. You can then save it as a shortcut. E.g.,

```
https://dev.azure.com/org1
```